QuestDB fails Kubernetes liveness probe when CPU is near 100%
I'm running QuestDB on Kubernetes and trying to use the suggested liveness probe:
https://github.com/questdb/questdb-kubernetes/blob/master/charts/questdb/values.yaml 

   httpGet:
     path: /status
     port: 9003
     scheme: HTTP

When the CPU is going to near 100% I see the liveness probe fail and the pod is killed.
I see some relevant messages in QuestDB log that it somehow stopped listening on port 9003 from time to time:
2024-10-25T09:58:22.427781Z E http-min-server been unable to accept connections for 5000ms, closing listener [serverFd=1155346202969]
2024-10-25T09:57:23.530090Z A http-min-server listening on 0.0.0.0:9003 [fd=1155346202969 backlog=4]
2024-10-25T09:56:37.433830Z E http-min-server been unable to accept connections for 5000ms, closing listener [serverFd=105076374923487]
2024-10-25T09:55:17.439768Z A http-min-server listening on 0.0.0.0:9003 [fd=105076374923487 backlog=4]

What can I do to make it work, and stay responsive on http://<server>:9003/status requests even on high CPU load?

You probably hit the connection limit to the http-min-server.
Even if you do not use multiple requests, when QuestDB is busy, using all available CPU it starts slipping on closing TCP connections and it may create a situation when multiple connections are still open.
To make it work with busy CPU, put line http.min.net.connection.limit=64 in QuestDB server.conf as it's described at https://questdb.io/docs/configuration/, I believe the default 4 is too low and should be increased in the future versions.
